# ¿Como implementar el siguiente codigo a una estructura?

Tags: dev-c++

El código que hice, simplemente me pide dos palabra, luego las compara y me muestra en el orden que va.

```
if(strcmp(palabra1,palabra2)>0){
    printf("En Orden: \n");
    printf("1- %s\n2- %s",palabra2,palabra1);
}
else{
    printf("En Orden: \n");
    printf("1- %s\n2- %s",palabra1,palabra2);
}
return 0;
```

Mi duda es, como lo implementaría a mi estructura

```
struct cliente
{
       int documento;
       char nombre[15];
       char apellido[15];
       char telefono[20];
       int ocupacion;
};
```

Para que lo ordene alfabéticamente!
Gracias.

Comment: No se entiende tu duda o pregunta, podrías dar mayor información

Comment: Una estructura puede contener funciones de la misma manera que una clase.